# Bug iphone: Subscribing to an observable returns to me that the first value it issued,

Tags: angular, rxjs

Can you tell me if the problem is in this code. I am trying to set up data polling. the responses following the response to the first request are not transmitted to the back-end and the observables that I have in return all have the same value as the first response. this even if the state changes in the back-end.

Example If the very first getStatus returns opened, the following requests are not transmitted and the observable responses will be opened

in my service i have following code

```
getIntervalStatus(sessionId: string): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {

    return this.getStatus(sessionId).pipe(
      map(
        (result: HttpResponse<string>) => {
          this.statusOpened = result.body.toLowerCase();
          this.utils.alertLog(this.getStatus, result.body.toLowerCase());
          this.statusEmit.next(this.statusOpened);
          if (this.statusOpened === 'opened' || this.statusOpened === 'closed') {
            this.getIntervalStatus(sessionId).subscribe( );
          }
          return result;
        }
      ),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.statusOpened = 'error';
        this.utils.alertLog(this.getStatus, JSON.stringify(err));
        this.statusEmit.error(err);
        throw err;
      })
    );

  }

getStatus(sessionId: string): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams().set('sessionId', sessionId);
    return this.http.post<string>(this.fullWsUrl + '/Payment/GetPaymentStatus', null,
      { observe: 'response', params: httpParams }).pipe(
         map((value: HttpResponse<string>) => {
          this.utils.alertLog(this.getStatus, value.status.toString());
          return value;
        })
      );
  }
```

in my component i have following code

```
      this.openSessionSubscription = this.device.openSession(amount, this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.utils.alertLog(this.device.getIntervalStatus, 'Session is opened');
          this.sessionIsOpened = true;
          // subject for information session is opened
          this.device.statusOpened = 'opened';

          this.device.statusEmit = new Subject<string>();
          this.statusEmitSubscriber = this.device.statusEmit.subscribe(
            status => {

              this.status = status;
              console.log(this.constructor.name + 'payment status', this.status);
              switch (this.status) {
                case 'opened':
                  break;
                case 'payed':
                  this.utils.alertLog(this.device.getIntervalStatus, 'statut payed');
                  this.localStorageService.storePaymentIsMade(true);
                  this.dbService.addOrderPaymentResult(ProcessResult.done, this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).subscribe();
                  this.router.navigate(['welcome/paying/paying_accepted']);
                  break;
                case 'closed':
                  this.utils.alertLog(this.device.getIntervalStatus, 'statut closed');
                  // this.paymentSessionIsClosed = true;
                  // this.dbService.addOrderPaymentResult(ProcessResult.error, this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).subscribe();
                  // this.utils.deleteSectionAction(this.printerVMService.getPrinterVM());
                  break;
                case 'used':
                  this.utils.alertLog(this.device.getIntervalStatus, 'status used');
                  // this.utils.deleteSectionAction(this.printerVMService.getPrinterVM());
                  break;
                default:
                  console.error('status don\'t exist');
                  this.utils.alertLog(this.device.getIntervalStatus, 'statut not exist');
                  this.utils.deleteSectionAction(this.printerVMService.getPrinterVM());
              }
            },
            error => {
              this.alert.success('statut error');
              console.error(this.translate.instant('PAYMENT.DEVICE.GETSTATUSERRORMSG'));
              this.utils.deleteSectionAction(this.printerVMService.getPrinterVM());
            }
          );

          this.utils.alertLog(this.device.getIntervalStatus, 'getIntervalStatusSubscription is call');
          this.getIntervalStatusSubscription = this.device.getIntervalStatus(this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).subscribe();

        },
        error => {
          // emit session not open
          console.error(this.translate.instant('PAYMENT.DEVICE.OPENERRORMSG'));
          this.utils.alertLog(this.device.openSession, 'open error');
          this.utils.deleteSectionAction(this.printerVMService.getPrinterVM());
        }
      );
```

Comment: I specify that it is only on the iphone that I have this problem

Comment: Can you recreate this using *minimal* code in stackblitz? You can test a stackblitz on iPhone to check.

Comment: Also, what is `this.utils.alertLog` doing?

Comment: this.utils.alertLog allows you to make popups to display return values. it's for debugging

Comment: can you tell me if this is the best way to write pooling data with angular??

Comment: There are a lot of nested subscriptions, which is never a good sign. And it's hard to tell what's going on as all of the code is all mixed in together. If you can't recreate the problem in a stackblitz, you're not going to have much luck asking such an open ended question here. You're basically asking for a code review, which is best done elsewhere.

Comment: I had a quick look at your service to remove the nested subscription: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mceib. This isn't going to solve your problem, but just a hint at how I would write your service function. I then looked at the component and backed away.

Comment: okay i will do a simpler code on stackblitz

Comment: I will test if your proposal works and I will give you a feedback

Comment: It won't! The nested subscriptions in your component are probably causing more issues. I would also try using `timer()` from rxjs rather than a recursive call for polling though, to answer your earlier question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

You want to poll your API until certain statuses are returned. If the status `opened` or `closed` is returned you want to repeat the request. If the status `payed`, `used`, or something else is returned, you want your component to perform an action.

#### The problem with your implementation

You are creating a lot of nested subscriptions, which is generally a bad idea. There should be one top-level subscriber - everything else can be chained as observables.

#### My design

I would firstly seek to remove all nested subscriptions. I would then like to use the `expand` operator for recursively chaining an observable - that's the polling taken care of.

I am going to create a `Status` type for strong typing.

The `getStatus` function will return `Observable<Status>`, as there is no need for it to return the full response.

For the purposes of the answer, I am going to simplify what you're doing. This may mean that I remove functionality you want, but I am going to focus mainly on the polling aspect. You should then be able to add any extra functionality back in.

#### My implementation

status

```js
export type Status = 'open' | 'closed' | 'payed' | 'used' | 'error';
```

service

```js
private continuePollingStatuses: Status[] = [
  'open', 'closed'
];

getIntervalStatus(sessionId: string): Observable<Status> {
  return this.getStatus(sessionId).pipe(
    expand((status: Status) => {
      if (this.continuePollingStatuses.includes(status)) {
        // repeat the request
        return this.getStatus(sessionId);
      }     
      // do not repeat the request
      return empty();
    }),
    catchError((err) => of('error'))
  );
}

private getStatus(sessionId: string): Observable<Status> {
  // cache-busting query param
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const url = `${this.fullWsUrl}/Payment/GetPaymentStatus?t=${timestamp}`;
  const httpParams = new HttpParams().set('sessionId', sessionId);
  const options = { observe: 'response', params: httpParams };
  return this.http.post<string>(url, null, options).pipe(
    map(response => response.body.toLowerCase())
  );
}
```

component

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const sessionId = this.printerVMService.getSessionId();
  this.service.getIntervalStatus(sessionId).pipe(
    switchMap((status: Status) => this.performAction(status))
  ).subscribe(status => {
    this.status = status;    

    switch (this.status) {
      case 'opened':        
      case 'closed':      
      case 'used': 
        break;
      case 'payed':        
        this.localStorageService.storePaymentIsMade(true);
        this.router.navigate(['welcome/paying/paying_accepted']);
        break;
      case 'error':
        console.error(this.translate.instant('PAYMENT.DEVICE.GETSTATUSERRORMSG'));
        this.utils.deleteSectionAction(this.printerVMService.getPrinterVM());
        break;
      default:
        console.error('status don\'t exist');
        this.utils.deleteSectionAction(this.printerVMService.getPrinterVM());
     }
   });
}

private performAction(status: Status): Observable<Status> {
  switch (status) {
    case 'payed':
      return this.dbService.addOrderPaymentResult(ProcessResult.done, 
        this.printerVMService.getSessionId()).pipe(
        map(() => of(status))
      );
  }

  return of(status);
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7gkixg

Comment: thank you for your help, i implemented the solution you proposed it works very well. unfortunately i was always in production my initial problem only on the iphone. I removed the serviceworker and pwa modules because I assumed that they can intercept requests but the problem is still not resolved

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a minimal stackblitz? You never posted a link

Comment: the code did not change. i can't reproduce in stackblitz. it happens only in production with iphone

Comment: You're probably on your own if you can't recreate (even by accessing a stackblitz on iPhone). Is it a public website that you post the link to?

Comment: it is a local intranet website

Comment: I think the first response to the status request is cached by the browser and then the browser then uses it as a response for the following get status requests. What is strange is that I have disabled all the caches of this getstatus request. I did it in the following way. ` const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Cache-Control', 'no-store').set('Content-Type', 'application/json' );`

Comment: You could always add a value to the querystring to avoid caching issues. I've updated `getStatus` in my answer

Comment: how i would have done if i was avoiding caching a get request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209535/discussion-between-faizou-aremou-and-kurt-hamilton).